# Notes folded into paper airplanes

Tags: slang

Do the notes that are folded into paper airplanes and thrown across classrooms by kids, have a special name?

Comment: "Paper Planes"?

Comment: I thought _paper plane notes_ went out of style with the advent of cell phones and texting. Are you writing a novel that takes place in the 1970s or something?

Comment: @J.R. they'll never be completely out of style while some schools still have no-phones-in-class rules, and while phones are both too heavy and too expensive to throw at someone's head without getting into serious trouble.

Comment: @JonHanna with advent of paper thin and flexible displays, kids will soon be able to type up the note on their phone, fold it into an airplane and throw it without breaking anyone's head.

Comment: @Mansour though they still won't until they're as cheap as paper.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used to call them *air mail* when I was at school, but this doesn't appear to have any sanction in the online dictionaries that I can find [(here)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/air+mail). The [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=air%20mail) has a different, but perhaps not entirely unrelated, definition of the term.

Comment: [Air mail launcher](http://www.perpetualkid.com/air-mail-notes-and-stand-launcher.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Everywhere I know, they're simply called paper planes and people know what this means.

Comment: Does that infer that there is a message written in it

Comment: Not necessarily, some kids just throw them across the room.

Comment: I believe OP specifically refers to a _message_ delivered by folded airplane - as in "air mail"

Comment: As @mplungjan mentioned, I don't mean any paper planes, only the ones with message on them.